# Is there any way in Azure Event Hub to figure out how many through put units are used at specified time?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Event Hub with Auto Inflate enabled and TU(Throughput Units) are 5. How can I check at what time how many TUs are used by Event Hub so that I can generate alerts for my customer?

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable Log Analytics to monitor these metrics on the AEH namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics

Azure Monitor has nice alerting features that you can leverage to monitor messaging metrics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric

Comment: I did not find any metric for throughput count. Please let me know the name.

Comment: You should check number of messages in and out. Btw, throughput is a capacity unit. Please read the following doc to understand relationship between message traffic and throughput units. Let me know if you have any questions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability